# velocity_x and animator causing error while trying to run flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

I started a project today, i want to do a form with flutter + dart and have seen that velocity_x looks interesting for front so i add its last version to my pubspec.yaml in VSC and 'flutter pub get' it.

Then i import it to my dart code and start running it.

Ended up with this error and am just starting dart so don't really know how to fix it.

[error: ../../../../../../Documents/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/velocity_x-3.2.0/lib/src/flutter/animated/animator.dart:119:9: Error: Type 'TickerMixin' not found.
final TickerMixin? tickerMixin;

../../../../../../Documents/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/velocity_x-3.2.0/lib/src/flutter/animated/animator.dart:119:9: Error: 'TickerMixin' isn't a type.
final TickerMixin? tickerMixin;

../../../../../../Documents/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/velocity_x-3.2.0/lib/src/flutter/animated/animator.dart:174:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'tickerMixin'.
tickerMixin: tickerMixin,

../../../../../../Documents/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animator-3.1.0/lib/src/animator.dart:18:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Animator({

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0un1.png)

edit : i'm dumb : https://github.com/iampawan/VelocityX/issues/109

"Adding below lines in pubspec.yaml should fix it for now. I will fix it in next update.

dependency_overrides:
animator: 3.0.0" iampawan

Comment: I think you should raised the issue to the VelocityX repository.
https://github.com/cncf/velocity/issues

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can fix this.

1. Using this in pubspec.yaml will fix this

```
dependency_overrides:
  animator: 3.0.0
```

2. Update VelocityX to v3.3.0

Comment: yes its is working as you said. i update my Velocity X and add dependency